# pre-load / pre-require directories of .js route files

Tags: node.js, express

Using Express with Node.js, we might do something like this:

```
app.use('api/:controller/:action/:id', function(req,res,next){

   var controller = req.params.controller;
   var action = req.params.action;

   var route = require('./routes/' + controller + '/' + action);

   route(req,res,next);

}
```

now this is all fine and well, except there is at least one problem: the route file is dynamically loaded at runtime if this file has not been 'require'd yet. Which means it's a little bit slower at least.

Does someone have a script that recurses through a directory and pre-loads/pre-requires all the .js files when a server first starts up?

I have a similar problem for the front-end as well, using RequireJS. The solution seems to be to write a bash script that writes out all the .js filepaths in a directory and its subdirectories to a text file. then when the server starts up, it reads that text file and requires all the files in the directory that are listed in the text file. Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/troygoode/node-require-directory ?

Comment: For front-end: webpack

Comment: thanks @stdob I might use webpack/browserify in the future but for now I am sticking with RequireJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an NPM module that does this for the front-end, doing it for Node.js / CommonJS is another story.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs-metagen

you can use it like so:

```
var grm = require('requirejs-metagen'); //you can use with Gulp

var controllersOpts = {
        inputFolder: './public/static/app/js/controllers/all',
        appendThisToDependencies: 'app/js/controllers/',
        appendThisToReturnedItems: '',
        eliminateSharedFolder: true,
        output: './public/static/app/js/meta/allControllers.js'
    };


grm(controllersOpts,function(err){
  //handle errors your own way
});
```

it generates a corresponding AMD/RequireJS module like so:

```
define(
    [
        "app/js/controllers/all/jobs",
        "app/js/controllers/all/users"
    ],
    function(){

        return {

            "jobs": arguments[0],
            "users": arguments[1]
        }
  });
```

you can also require subdirectories and all that stuff like so:

```
 var allViewsOpts = {
        inputFolder: './public/static/app/js/jsx',
        appendThisToDependencies: 'app/js/',
        appendThisToReturnedItems: '',
        eliminateSharedFolder: true,
        output: './public/static/app/js/meta/allViews.js'
    }

 grm(allViewsOpts );
```

which generates output like so:

```
define([
        "app/js/jsx/BaseView",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/FluxCart",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/FluxCartApp",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/FluxProduct",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/Item",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/Job",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/JobsList",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/listView",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/Picture",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/PictureList",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/RealTimeSearchView",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/Service",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/ServiceChooser",
        "app/js/jsx/reactComponents/todoList",
        "app/js/jsx/relViews/getAll/getAll",
        "app/js/jsx/relViews/jobs/jobsView",
        "app/js/jsx/standardViews/dashboardView",
        "app/js/jsx/standardViews/overviewView",
        "app/js/jsx/standardViews/pictureView",
        "app/js/jsx/standardViews/portalView",
        "app/js/jsx/standardViews/registeredUsersView",
        "app/js/jsx/standardViews/userProfileView"
    ],
    function(){

        return {

            "BaseView": arguments[0],
            "reactComponents/FluxCart": arguments[1],
            "reactComponents/FluxCartApp": arguments[2],
            "reactComponents/FluxProduct": arguments[3],
            "reactComponents/Item": arguments[4],
            "reactComponents/Job": arguments[5],
            "reactComponents/JobsList": arguments[6],
            "reactComponents/listView": arguments[7],
            "reactComponents/Picture": arguments[9],
            "reactComponents/PictureList": arguments[10],
            "reactComponents/RealTimeSearchView": arguments[11],
            "reactComponents/Service": arguments[12],
            "reactComponents/ServiceChooser": arguments[13],
            "relViews/getAll/getAll": arguments[14],
            "relViews/jobs/jobsView": arguments[15],
            "standardViews/dashboardView": arguments[16],
            "standardViews/overviewView": arguments[17],
            "standardViews/pictureView": arguments[18],
            "standardViews/portalView": arguments[19],
            "standardViews/registeredUsersView": arguments[20],
            "standardViews/userProfileView": arguments[21]
        }
  });
```

I need to update the library so it returns the stream so you can handle when it completes, otherwise it works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `io.js`, it can preload modules using command-line `-r` or `--require`:

```
iojs -r <module_name> server.js
```